# wso2 is missing wso2server.bat and Analytics

Tags: wso2

I am trying to setup my first wso2 esb server but get stuck at the quick guide.

Following this guide:https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500/Quick+Start+Guide#QuickStartGuide-Introducingthesample

Downloaded the esb from this page: http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/

The guide states "Go to http:// wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/, click Analytics to download the ESB analytics ZIP file...", but there is nu such button or link.

Then the guide states "Start WSO2 ESB server by ...
...On Windows:  wso2server.bat --run"
I am on windows, but there is no wso2server.bat in the bin folder.

There is a wso2server.bat file in the folder /wso2/analytics/bin.
If a run that analytics is started (or so it seems) Do i still need to download analytics seperatly?

Where can i get the correct/working wso2server.bin for the esb?

The quick guides/tutorials seem the be incorrect/out of date, anyone know a good quickstart guide/wso2 for dummy's i can follow?

We are just trying to determine what esb we are going to use. In theory wso2 is our best shot, but so far the experience hase been anyting but smooth :(

Comment: WSO2 esb server is different from WSO2 analytics server, download proper WSO2 ESB server from http://wso2.com/more-downloads/esb

Comment: For presentation checkout http://wso2.com/training/enterprise-service-bus-developer-fundamentals

Comment: Documentation - https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB500

Comment: @PRATHAPS thank you for your comment.

this http://wso2.com/more-downloads/esb link helped me a lot.

Comment: You are able to download and run the ESB server ?

Comment: Yes i am, but now i am strugling to get a realy simple thing running.
A  soap proxy, getting a fault back "ActionMismatch"
Wanted to trace it but the documentation is incorrect. Soap tracer is not present. eventualty found out i had to install it with the feature install option. Soap tracer does not show the headers. mediation tracer is also not installed by default, but i cannot install it from the repository because of some dependency issues or something. The way things have been going i dont think we'l be using this product. I am about 2 seconds away from throwing the towel in the ring.

Comment: WSO2 documentation is limited, more over no active forums

Answer (score 1):

Sorry about your negative experience with WSO2 ESB. You may seems to follow documentation for a different product version. Let me point you few resources so that you can utilize.

First of all WSO2 ESB 5.0.0 is fairly old which is released on Aug 2016. WSO2's next generation integration product is [WSO2 Enterprise Integrator](https://wso2.com/integration). Download page is [here](https://wso2.com/integration#download) and public cloud option is also available [here](https://wso2.com/integration#cloud). This combines ESB capabilities with business process, micro-services, message brokering and data integration to make it a more complete offering. Quick start guide for latest EI is [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/EI611/Quick+Start+Guide).

If you need any help you can ask the community either through here tagging your question appropriately or emailing to dev@wso2.org. If you need profession assistance from WSO2 you will have to reach out to WSO2 via '[Contact](https://wso2.com/contact/) Us' option in the web site.

Hope this helps!!

Answer (score 0):

> The guide states "Go to http:// wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/, click Analytics to download the ESB analytics ZIP file...", but there is nu such button or link.

To download `Analytics`, go to [Previous Releases](https://wso2.com/integration/previous-releases/) page, then select version 5.0.0 of `Enterprise Service Bus`. After selecting version 5.0.0, `Analytics` download link will appear. The download link is [WSO2 5.0.0 Analytics](https://product-dist.wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus/5.0.0/wso2esb-analytics-5.0.0.zip).

For more advanced info about `WSO2 ESB 5.0.0`, visit [WSO2 ESB 5.0.0: Downloading and Installing the tooling](https://www.yenlo.com/blog/downloading-and-installing-the-wso2-esb-5.0.0-tooling)